Efficient algorithm for partial reordering
Consider the following array of objects:
[
{v: 'a'},
{v: 'b'},
{v: 'c', ptr: 'b'},
{v: 'd', ptr: 'a'},
{v: 'e'},
]

Some of the objects contain a ptr property, referencing the v property value of an object that it should directly preceed. Two  objects will never attempt to directly preceed the same object, and there will never be a loop (e.g. a->b->c->a) in the array.
Therefore, here are two possible valid rearrangements of the objects:
[
{v: 'e'},
{v: 'd', ptr: 'a'},
{v: 'a'},
{v: 'c', ptr: 'b'},
{v: 'b'},
]

[
{v: 'c', ptr: 'b'},
{v: 'b'},
{v: 'd', ptr: 'a'},
{v: 'a'},
{v: 'e'}
]

It doesn't matter at all where objects appear in the output, if there is no ptr property referencing it. All that matters is that certain objects directly preceed others where the ptr property requests it.
What is a reasonably efficient algorithm to perform this kind of rearrangement?
Although the data is guaranteed to not contain loops, the rearrangement should be careful not to get into an infinite loop where it keeps rearranging the objects forever.
Note that although these examples use strings for v and ptr, the actual application will involve DOM elements as the values for v and ptr references. Therefore, the solution should only be able to compare v and ptr properties for equality.

ok, i think you should add this information in your question

If you think of the array as describing a graph, where v values are nodes and objects with ptr values describe edges, then an ordering of the nodes is equivalent to a topological sort. What I don't see in the question is anything that indicates how to order the other objects, ones without ptr values.

@danh thanks, it doesn't matter at all where the other objects appear in the output. All that matters is that certain objects directly preceed others where the ptr property requests it

So there is no sort of v ... just the chaining of ptr correct?

@danh: It's a little stricter than a topological sort, because objects with a ptr property have to directly precede the corresponding object. With a topological sort, if a had an outgoing edge to b and c had no incident edges, a, c, b would be a valid order.

@SpencerMay correct - in the real-world application, it would be impossible to sort v, since they are just DOM element references and not actually strings

Figure out which objects have another object pointing to them. Then, for each object that doesn't have another object pointing to it, add that object and everything in the following ptr chain to the output:
let val_to_obj = new Map();
let has_predecessor = new Set();
for (let obj of arr) {
    val_to_obj.set(obj.v, obj);
    if ('ptr' in obj) {
        has_predecessor.add(obj.ptr);
    }
}
let res = [];
for (let obj of arr) {
    if (has_predecessor.has(obj.v)) {
        continue;
    }
    while (obj !== undefined) {
        res.push(obj);
        obj = val_to_obj.get(obj.ptr);
    }
}


I know this has been answered but I still want to post mine :p
Added a few more chains for testing as well. The root of each chain is where the resulting chain will stem, so even though the chain starting at c is defined before the unchained g, the last element i is the root of chain c, thus its entire chain is positioned there.


var st = [
    {v: 'a'},
    {v: 'f', ptr: 'e'},
    {v: 'b', ptr: 'h'},
    {v: 'c', ptr: 'b'},
    {v: 'd', ptr: 'a'},
    {v: 'e'},
    {v: 'h'},
    {v: 'g'},
    {v: 'i', ptr: 'c'}
]

function createChain(x) {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < x.length) {
        // if chaining
        if (x[i]?.ptr) {
            // find index of chained element
            let follows = x.findIndex(y => y.v == x[i].ptr);
            if (follows > -1) {
                let offset = 0;
                // search for already-chained elements with `follows`
                while (x[follows+offset+1] && x[follows+offset]?.ptr == x[follows+offset+1].v) {
                    offset++;
                }
                // splicing elements before index requires an offset
                i = follows < i ? i-offset : i;
                // offset calculations were non inclusive of follows, +1
                x.splice(i, 0, ...x.splice(follows, offset+1));
                // reset index to offset end position
                i += offset-1;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return x;
}

console.log(createChain(st));




Thanks, I'll think this over to see if there might be any missing edge cases

All the searching and splicing produce a really bad time complexity for this code - I think it might even be O(N^3).

@user2357112 I've made an update to my post that has dropped my runtime by ~50% by searching for existing chains following the searched variable follows. I'm not entirely sure how to calculate a complexity value, I just do a time difference lol

@AndrewParks i've made an update, I tested a bit more and it seems to still pass everything I can throw at it. Hopefully it does for you too!

Collect items with ptr and copy the input with inserting ptr items before their targets:


const input = [
  {v: 'a'},
  {v: 'b'},
  {v: 'c', ptr: 'b'},
  {v: 'd', ptr: 'a'},
  {v: 'e'},
]

const pres = input.reduce((r, item) => ('ptr' in item && r.set(item.ptr, item), r), new Map);

const prefill = (item, r) => {
  const pre = pres.get(item.v);
  if(!pre) return;
  pres.delete(item.v);
  prefill(pre, r);
  r.push(pre);
};

const result = input.reduce((r, item) => ('ptr' in item || (prefill(item, r), r.push(item)), r), []);

console.log(result);



And a benchmark:
` Chrome/123
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                   n=6       |       n=60        |       n=600       |      n=6000     
Alexander     ■ 1.00x x1m 187 | ■ 1.00x   x1m 613 | ■ 1.00x x100k 472 | ■ 1.00x x10k 558
user2357112     1.33x x1m 249 |   2.82x x100k 173 |   3.39x  x10k 160 |   3.01x  x1k 168
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `



let offset = 0;
const $chunk = (offset++, [
  {v: 'a' + offset},
  {v: 'b' + offset},
  {v: 'c', ptr: 'b' + offset},
  {v: 'd' + offset, ptr: 'a' + offset},
  {v: 'e', ptr: 'f' + offset},
  {v: 'f' + offset, ptr: 'd' + offset}
]);

const $input = [];

// @benchmark user2357112
let arr = $input;
let val_to_obj = new Map();
let has_predecessor = new Set();
for (let obj of arr) {
    val_to_obj.set(obj.v, obj);
    if ('ptr' in obj) {
        has_predecessor.add(obj.ptr);
    }
}
let res = [];
for (let obj of arr) {
    if (has_predecessor.has(obj.v)) {
        continue;
    }
    while (obj !== undefined) {
        res.push(obj);
        obj = val_to_obj.get(obj.ptr);
    }
}
res;

// @benchmark Alexander

const pres = $input.reduce((r, item) => ('ptr' in item && r.set(item.ptr, item), r), new Map);

const prefill = (item, r) => {
  const pre = pres.get(item.v);
  if(!pre) return;
  pres.delete(item.v);
  prefill(pre, r);
  r.push(pre);
};

$input.reduce((r, item) => ('ptr' in item || (prefill(item, r), r.push(item)), r), []);
/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




This fails on an input of [{v: 'a'}, {v: 'b', ptr: 'a'}, {v: 'c', ptr: 'b'}].

Thanks, nice approach. I'm a little worried about the limits that could be imposed on this approach due to recursion (and thus a stack overflow)

@AndrewParks the ptr chain should be really long i guess
